# ImportError: No module named mininet.log

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, mininet

I am working on `mininet` when I run `miniedit` without `sudo` it gives me error

```
*** Mininet must run as root.
```

But when I run it as root it gives me a new error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./miniedit.py", line 27, in <module>
    from mininet.log import info, debug, warn, setLogLevel
ImportError: No module named mininet.log
```

Please help me resolve this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I make a test with pycharm and if you install the library with the command :
`pip install mininet`

your import may not have any error

maybe you installed your library with : `sudo pip install mininet` and your library is only available for root user

try `sudo pip uninstall mininet` and `pip install mininet`

Answer (score 4):

Try :

`PYTHON=python3 util/install.sh -fnv` from `https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/INSTALL`

Comment: what does -fnv denote?

Comment: -f: install Open(F)low.
-n: install Mini(N)et dependencies + core files.
-V <version>: install a particular version of Open (V)switch on Ubuntu. 
Source : https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/util/install.sh line 870.